# dataframe transformation python products atrributes values

Tags: python, pandas, attributes, product

I have an excel file with products like this below. Is it possible to align the same kind of attributes to same column using python?

**I have this**

| category | name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| board games | board game 1 | kind | family | box color | red | weight | 0.7 |
| board games | board game 2 | kind | card game | box color | blue | lenght | 25 |
| board games | board game 3 | box color | green | weight | 0.5 | lenght | 32 |

**Desired output**

| category | name | kind | box color | weight | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| board games | board game1 | family games | red | 0.7 |  |
| board games | board game2 | card games | blue |  | 25 |
| board games | board game3 |  | green | 0.5 | 32 |

**i have an other case with duplicate values.**

| category | name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smartphones | samsung1 | sim type | dual | color | green | ram | 4GB | Storage | 128GB | year | 2021 |
| smartphones | samsung2 | sim type | dual | color | green | ram | 4GB | storage | 256GB | year | 2021 |
| smartphones | xiaomi3 | sim type | dual | color | blue | ram | 6GB | length | 32mm | Storage | 128GB |

**desired output:**

| category | name | sim type | color | ram | Storage | length | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smartphones | samsung1 | dual | green | 4GB | 128GB | nan | 2021 |
| smartphones | samsung2 | dual | green | 4GB | 256GB | nan | 2021 |
| smartphones | xiaomi3 | dual | blue | 6GB | 128GB | 32mm | nan |

**error message:**

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Np5.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV36z.png)

**UPDATE_2:**

Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

| category | name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smartphones | samsung1 | sim type | dual | color | green | ram | 4GB | Storage | 128GB | year | 2021 | camera | yes | fingerprint | yes | accelometer | yes | gyroscope | yes | NFC | yes |
| smartphones | samsung2 | sim type | dual | color | green | ram | 4GB | storage | 256GB | year | 2021 | camera | yes | fingerprint | yes |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| smartphones | xiaomi3 | sim type | dual | color | blue | ram | 6GB | length | 32mm | Storage | 128GB | camera | yes | fingerprint | yes |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**desired output:**

| category | name | sim type | color | ram | Storage | length | year | camera | fingerprint | accelometer | gyroscope | NFC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smartphones | samsung1 | dual | green | 4GB | 128GB | nan | 2021 | yes | yes | yes | yes | no |
| smartphones | samsung2 | dual | green | 4GB | 256GB | nan | 2021 | yes | yes | nan | nan | nan |
| smartphones | xiaomi3 | dual | blue | 6GB | 128GB | 32mm | nan | yes | yes | nan | nan | nan |

[error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZthp.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the excel file. There might be a better way to read it in or use some other approach

Comment: thanks fo your comment.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/49225829536b2539dd325df75c56f88020220423175023/d4972c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

To solve duplicate issue, you can try:

```
out = df.set_index(['category', 'name'], append=True).melt(ignore_index=False)
m = out['variable'].astype(int) % 2 == 1
out = (pd.concat([out.loc[m, 'value'].rename('variable'),
                  out.loc[~m, 'value']], axis=1)
         .set_index('variable', append=True)['value']
         .unstack('variable').reset_index(['category', 'name'])
         .rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

| category | name | Storage | color | length | ram | sim type | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smartphones | samsung1 | 128GB | green | nan | 4GB | dual | 2021 |
| smartphones | samsung2 | 256GB | green | nan | 4GB | dual | 2021 |
| smartphones | xiaomi3 | 128GB | blue | 32mm | 6GB | dual | nan |

---

**Old answer**

You can mainly use `stack` and `unstack` to rearrange your dataframe:

```
# Separate odd (names) and even (values) columns
out = (pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 2::2].stack().droplevel(1),
                  df.iloc[:, 3::2].stack().droplevel(1)], axis=1)
         .set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack(0))

out = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :2], out], axis=1)
```

Output:

| category | name | box color | kind | lenght | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| board games | board game 1 | red | family | nan | 0.7 |
| board games | board game 2 | blue | card game | 25 | nan |
| board games | board game 3 | green | nan | 32 | 0.5 |

Comment: thank you very much! I'll try your approach.

Comment: Did you try the code? Does it work for you?

Comment: When my file contains unique values it works perfect but when i vahe duplicates like same color in different product (row), it gives me the error below

   3783         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3784         if not self._index_as_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3785             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3786 
   3787     def reindex(
 
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @IoannaAspasiaArgyrou. Can you update your post with a such example please?

Comment: i made an edit to my post adding this example

Comment: @IoannaAspasiaArgyrou. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: No, it keeps giving me the same error
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I add two images in my post,  so you can see exactly the error.

Comment: Yes, but keeps giving this error. If i put unique values on odd columns (for example changing green to green_1) it works perfectly, otherwise stucks.

Comment: It works!! i found the problem. 
I had write
pd.read_excel(f, dtype=str).fillna('')

i delete this part  -> .fillna('') and the problem solved! 

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I found a case where i have the same error. i made an update in my post.

Comment: Your last update works for me... I can't reproduce your error

Comment: i add a wetransfer url with my actual excel file.

Comment: I found the problem. I have duplicate feature names. Thank you very much!! I accepted your answer.

Comment: I made an update to my post, called "update2" because i found a new case, where the code stucks.  thank you in advance!
@Corralien